# ContentValues Object comparing with Database wont work

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to compare a ContentValues Object with values from a Database, but I can't figure out why the following wont work:

```
ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();
try{
    JSONObject ClickedItem = new JSONObject();
    ClickedItem = resultArray.getJSONObject(position);
    werte.put("name", ClickedItem.getString("name"));
    werte.put("hersteller", ClickedItem.getString("hersteller"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Whoops - something went wrong!3");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Boolean allreadyAdded = false;
Cursor devicesCursor = mDatenbank.query("addedDevices", new String[] {"name", "hersteller"}, null, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(devicesCursor);
devicesCursor.moveToFirst();

for (int i=0;i<devicesCursor.getCount();i++){

    if(devicesCursor.getString(0) == werte.getAsString("name")){
        allreadyAdded = true;
    }
    devicesCursor.moveToNext();
}

if(allreadyAdded==false){                       
    mDatenbank.insert("addedDevices", null, werte);
}
```

The `if(devicesCursor.getString(0) == werte.getAsString("name"))` just wont work and I can't figure out why. System.out.println shows me that devicesCursor and were both have the same value but already Added won't be set to true...

Answer (score 1):

Because you can not compare two string using `==` operator, Your if condition never be gone true.

To compare two strings just use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCases()` from **Java String Class**..

```
if(devicesCursor.getString(0).equals(werte.getAsString("name")))
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks a lot! But could u please explain how thats different from what I had?

Comment: With the == operator you compare the references of two String objects, not the values. Therefore You need .equals()

Comment: `==` operator use for compare tow reference of Object. To compare value of string you have to use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`.